# Rails 4 ActionController::base helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, helper

After reading in the Rails api documentation, and watching this [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules), I tried to use the helper method in one of my controllers as such:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper :readers, :otherhelper, :otherhelper2

  def endpointMethod
    readers_helper_method()
  end
```

And then in `app/helpers/readers_helper.rb`:

```
module ReadersHelper
  def readers_helper_method
    ...
  end
end
```

But that gives me a NoMethodError for the call to `readers_helper_method` in the PostsController.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
helper :readers
```

is like:

```
require 'readers_helper'
include ReadersHelper
```

you see, they are should be Class methods, not Instance methods ...

So, you could call

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper :readers, :otherhelper, :otherhelper2

  readers_helper_method() # hint self is current class
```

not

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper :readers, :otherhelper, :otherhelper2

  def endpointMethod
    readers_helper_method() # hit self is current action
  end
```

Comment: I don't think I follow.
Moving the method call should not change whether it is a class or instance method?